# What is this gutter part and how do I keep birds out

Tags: gutters

What is this part of the gutter? It looks like regular drain with some piece on top? Birds keep nesting in it and I'm trying to find a way to keep them out that is easy to do. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Back up and take a wider photo for context. That's an unusual arrangement so it probably for an unusual reason.

Comment: It is kind of odd enough that the birds are using it for it's intended purpose.

Comment: Lol. On the other side of that wall is a deck's drain pipe. I will get a better picture in the morning.

Comment: A 12 inch length of rain gutter, half way up a wall, with a solid cover on top.  Either a bird house or there is an outside water tap in it.  Would add possible spittoon, but not with a solid cover(maybe if cover is hinged).

Answer (score 2):

Don't see what the confusion is here.  When you see this it's almost always to drain a raised edge rooftop or patio or something.  You can adjust the cover so there is no hole for the birds to get through.  Use screws as you may want to remove it one day for a cleanout.  If the pipe draining into it from the deck is significant size, block it with mesh.  Bird can't get in, deck still drains, no problem.

Comment: I would use a sturdy wire mesh. An annoyed bird might tear up plastic mesh to get back into her preferred nesting spot.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the purpose, but you could replace that "cover" with a tightly fitted leaf guard section cut to fit.  I see metal and plastic versions at your local home stores.